# unable to display application icon for c# project(Vs10 windows application)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have added the icon.ico setting to resources.resx, i am able see the icon.ico file in the resources folder.
this automatically generated the following code in Resources.Designer.cs

```
    internal static System.Drawing.Icon icon {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("icon", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Icon)(obj));
        }
    }
```

i have also inserted following code in my Form.designer.cs.

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.icon")));
```

but i keep getting "missing manifest resource"exception in above line when i try to build the project.
could some one tell me what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure why above solution dint work. 
following line did the work for me

```
this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(ZebraAES256EncryptionUtility.Properties.Resources.icon,Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to embed the icon into your dll:
Right click on Resources file -> Properties
BuildAction:"EmbeddedResource"